# Installing and using user-defined package

Tags: packages, installing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows)

I have put together a user-defined package stored in a `.sty` file.

Using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7, I've placed the file in the same directory as all other `.sty` files and I've run `initexmf --update-fndb`, yet `pdflatex` is still giving me the `mypackage.sty not found` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you placed the file `mypackage.sty` in a directory named `mypackage` in the LOCALTEXMF tree? If so, be sure to bring up the "MiKTeX Settings" dialogue page -- once up, it'll say "MiKTeX Options" in the header -- click on the "Roots" tab, and enter the location of the LOCALTEXMF directory (e.g., `\localtexmf`) by clicking on the "Add..." button. Then go back to the "General" tab and click on "Refresh FNDB".

Comment: I have `mypackage.sty` in a `mypackage` directory. This directory is in the same directory as all the other packages. MiKTeX Options shows this be under a MiKTeX-maintained root directory. Do I still need to "Add"? I try doing "Refresh FNDB" but still get the error.